# Using aviation formula (Lat/lon given radial and distance); longitude does not return

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude

This is the formula for calculating a lat/lon given radial and distance, found here: http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#LL

```
lat=asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d)+cos(lat1)*sin(d)*cos(tc))
 IF (cos(lat)=0)
    lon=lon1      // endpoint a pole
 ELSE
    lon=mod(lon1-asin(sin(tc)*sin(d)/cos(lat))+pi,2*pi)-pi
 ENDIF
```

Here is the code I am currently using (all inputs and outputs calculated in radians):

```
nx = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat0) * Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat0) * Math.sin(d) * Math.cos(c));

ny = mod(lon0 - Math.asin(sin(c) * Math.sin(d) / Math.cos(lat1)) + Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;

return [nx, ny];
```

}

nx prints with no problems, but ny does not print.

Comment: `nx prints` ... what do you mean by "prints"? what do you mean by "does not print"? show the code that "prints"

Comment: what is "mod"? a function? show that function ... do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm going to be publishing a point at nx,ny on a map, but while troubleshooting I just set it up window alert to show nx and ny, to make sure the numbers are coming out correctly. nx is showing, nothing is showing up for ny. I believe mod refers to modulus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mod` is modulus operator

Change:

```
ny = mod(lon0 - Math.asin(sin(c) * Math.sin(d) / Math.cos(lat1)) + Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI) - Math.PI;
```

to

```
// ....................vvvvv note, I spotted this omission as well
ny =((lon0 - Math.asin(Math.sin(c) * Math.sin(d) / Math.cos(lat1)) + Math.PI) % (2 * Math.PI)) - Math.PI;
```

or create a function

```
function mod(a, b) {
    return a % b;
}
```

but, you will need to fix up that lack of Math. above